# OSMNX RuntimeError: b'No such file or directory'

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA', network_type='drive')
ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
```

but I obtain this error output:

---

```
runfile('C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/osmnx-0.8.2-py_0/site-packages/osmnx/Isochrones 1.py', wdir='C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/osmnx-0.8.2-py_0/site-packages/osmnx')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-48f64135d3f9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/osmnx-0.8.2-py_0/site-packages/osmnx/Isochrones 1.py', wdir='C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/osmnx-0.8.2-py_0/site-packages/osmnx')

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/pkgs/osmnx-0.8.2-py_0/site-packages/osmnx/Isochrones 1.py", line 15, in <module>
    graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='drive')

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osmnx\core.py", line 1867, in graph_from_place
    custom_filter=custom_filter)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osmnx\core.py", line 1733, in graph_from_polygon
    polygon_utm, crs_utm = project_geometry(geometry=polygon)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osmnx\projection.py", line 53, in project_geometry
    gdf_proj = project_gdf(gdf, to_crs=to_crs, to_latlong=to_latlong)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osmnx\projection.py", line 119, in project_gdf
    projected_gdf = gdf.to_crs(utm_crs)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 443, in to_crs
    geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 304, in to_crs
    proj_in = pyproj.Proj(self.crs, preserve_units=True)

  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 358, in __new__
    return _proj.Proj.__new__(self, projstring)

  File "_proj.pyx", line 84, in _proj.Proj.__cinit__

RuntimeError: b'No such file or directory'
```

---

Could anyone help me fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your pyproj installation. If you follow the "if you're having any trouble" installation instructions in OSMnx's documentation it should fix it (i.e., pyproj is more reliable in a virtual environment): https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation

The issue is discussed and solved here: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/203

See also [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/205) and [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/830#issuecomment-426116505)